# check if record is last or first in list with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a **list of objects**. 
I want to determine when the user will get the **first or last object in the list**, that way I can disable some buttons on the page.

For example I might have some boolean and if the object requested is last or first in the list, then it will return `true`, otherwise `false`.

Any idea?

Comment: Some context is missing which may affect the answer. How are you currently returning the requested object? What does your code look like? Are you already searching the list for the object? If so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrtie an extension method such as

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static bool IsLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, T item)
    {
        var last =  items.LastOrDefault();
        if (last == null)
            return false;
        return item.Equals(last); // OR Object.ReferenceEquals(last, item)
    }

    public static bool IsFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, T item)
    {
        var first =  items.FirstOrDefault();
        if (first == null)
            return false;
        return item.Equals(first);
    }

    public static bool IsFirstOrLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, T item)
    {
        return items.IsFirst(item) || items.IsLast(item);
    }
 }
```

You can use it like

```
 IEnumerable<User> users = // something
 User user = // something

 bool isFirstOrLast = users.IsFirstOrLast(user);
```

Comment: Used indiscriminately, this might have disastrous performance characteristics... for instance, called in a loop.

Comment: Might also lead to false positives if the first/last item is not distinct in the sequence

Comment: First/Last extensions check if the `IEnumerable` instance is `IList`. If so, they use `list[0]` or `list[list.Count - 1]`. But if it is not `IList` yes, there will be some overhead. On the other hand, if you need to access some certain elements of a collection and you choose a collection implementation which does not support access by index, it would be a general design flaw.

Answer (score 8):

If your list of objects is indeed a `List`, it might be better to use it explicitly (adapted the Mehmet Ataş's answer):

```
static class ListExtensions
{
  public static bool IsFirst<T>(this List<T> items, T item)
  {
    if (items.Count == 0)
      return false;
    T first =  items[0];
    return item.Equals(first);
  }

  public static bool IsLast<T>(this List<T> items, T item)
  {
    if (items.Count == 0)
      return false;
    T last =  items[items.Count-1];
    return item.Equals(last);
  }
}
```

This way you eliminate the LINQ overhead (it's not much, but it's significant). However, your code must use `List<T>` for this to work.

Comment: _adapted the Mehmet Ataş's answer_ - this is so unnecessary.

Comment: I mean the implementation not the credit. `First`/`Last` already can `IList` so implementing it with a `List<>` is rather redudant.

Comment: @t3chb0t,  Those work as `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods, these will be marginally faster, as they work with the `List` / `IList` directly.

Comment: However, main thing, according to me, is that it is implied, since they don't have to, they don't enumerate the collection, something that cannot be guaranteed for a generic `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourObject = yourList[0];
if(list.Count > 0)
    if(yourObject == list.First() || yourobject == list.Last())
    {
     //item is either first or last
    }
```

**But remember to check if the list contains atleast 1 item**, otherwise you will end up with exception from [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx), [Last](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.last.aspx).

The above will compare the reference for the objects, you can compare their values by implementing a custom [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) or you may compare their values.

Comment: ...also worth being aware that in most/all cases, `.Last()` causes a full enumeration of the source sequence.

Comment: If the `IEnumerable` is indeed a `List`, `Last()` will just return `list[list.Count-1]`