# Check if last Row Entity Framework through Select

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Ok people, before bashing, this is a little bit different from what I've investigated.

I currently have the following code:

```
public async Task<ParticipantTournament> GetParticipantTournamentByDescending(int tournamentId, int participantId)
        {
            var response = await _dbRepositories.TournamentParticipantMatchRepository
                .Where(x => x.TournamentId == tournamentId)
                .OrderByDescending(y => y.TournamentMatch.RoundNumber)
                .ThenByDescending(y => y.TournamentMatch.Id)
                .Include(x => x.Tournament)
                .Include(x => x.Participant1)
                .Include(x => x.Participant2)
                .Include(x => x.TournamentMatch)
                .Select(z => new TournamentParticipantMatchLogicDto
                {


                    IsLastMatch = OneTrue() // <==== Problem here,
                    TournamentParticipantMatch = z


                }).Where(x => (x.TournamentParticipantMatch.Participant1Id == participantId || x.TournamentParticipantMatch.Participant2Id == participantId))
                .ToListAsync();
            return new ParticipantTournament
            {
                ParticipantMatches = response,
            };


        }
        /**
         * This may be something super dumb. But I couldnt' come up with something better. 
         * How do I detect the latest match? 
         * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687136/check-if-record-is-last-or-first-in-list-with-linq
         * 
         * Well, after digging a little bit, I've found that this is not possible :o
         * */
        private bool  OneTrue()
        {
            if (!IsLast) return false;
            IsLast = false;
            return true;
        }
```

I am building a tournament platform. I need to know which is the last match so I can give the players 5 rounds instead of 3. Instead of creating a new column and filling it with false or true, I decided to filter it out. I thought that I could take advantage of LINQ's deferred execution:

1. I would Select the whole data set from the tournament.
2. I would then order it by descending and select the first row as the last one. (All the matches were inserted in order, so the biggest id is the last one)

   3. Then filter out which are from the users and which are not.

Possible solutions I think it could work: 
- Create a boolean column that will hold "true" value for the last matches. 
- Using Specification Pattern (Which I don't know how to apply in this situation. Tried using Expressions and Func but couldn't map them correctly) 
- Load all the Ids and select the last one of those Ids. Compare those Ids with the ones that all the users have. Unfortunately this would add an extra roundtrip to the database.

What should I do?

Thanks!

P.S: The OneTrue() method it does what it does, it returns true once, and then it returns false. (Didn't find anything else after a quick Google search)

**Edit**
For clarification purposes: 
[image]

The tables show a simulation of the data I currently have. I only need to extract what the current user needs, so I don't need the other 2 rows (which you can see in table #2). Once I select those two rows I exclude the other ones, which could potentially have the last match, but by only selecting this 2 rows I will not know. I'm trying to save any redundancy by trying to query it from the first try. I know that the last match Id is the last of the tournament

So what I was trying to do, is to order them all by descending (because they are in order), and select the last one as the last match.

Comment: The reason your code wont work is that you cannot call a method in the query because the method cannot be translated to sql. You could materialize the query to memory by calling `.ToList()` before the `.Select()` (and you will probably want the `.Where()` before the `.ToList()` also.

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand your query, but can't you just omit `IsLastMatch = OneTrue()` (so it defaults to `false`) and after the query, `response.First().IsLastMatch = true;` (assuming your query always returns at least one `TournamentParticipantMatchLogicDto`)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Thanks a bunch for the comments! I've just updated my question. What I want to do is to avoid as many roundtrips to the database as possible. I was trying to put everything down to a single query. If that's not possible I would then extract all the values and do a post-filter.

Comment: I still think you only need the one query (and it could be simplified by having one `.Where()` - the first one includes both conditions - `tournamentId` and `participantId`) and then all you need to do is `response.First().IsLastMatch = true;` (which will set the one with `MatchId=15` to `true` without making any extra database calls)

Comment: Or is it the one with `MatchId=17` that you want to mark as `IsLastMatch` (but if its not associated with `participantId`, then the results will not include a record with `IsLastMatch=true`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Exactly. Your last comment nailed it. That's my exact problem.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: In case I would do multiple queries, would it be better to store the info in the database instead? I mean, create a boolean column and set it to either true or false to see if that's the last match.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117147/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-jose-a).

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just query your subset of data after your return it with linq, like:

```
var temp = from e in _dbRepositories.TournamentParticipantMatchRepository
           where (from f in _dbRepositories.TournamentParticipantMatchRepository
                  where f.TournamentId == tournamentId)
                   .Include(x => x.Tournament)
            .Include(x => x.Participant1)
            .Include(x => x.Participant2)
            .Include(x => x.TournamentMatch)
            .Select(z => new TournamentParticipantMatchLogicDto
            {


                IsLastMatch = false, // <==== Problem here,
                TournamentParticipantMatch = z


            }).Where(x => (x.TournamentParticipantMatch.Participant1Id == participantId || x.TournamentParticipantMatch.Participant2Id == participantId))
            .ToListAsync();

 int maxResult= temp.Max(t => t.TournamentParticipantMatch.Id);
var update= temp.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TournamentParticipantMatch.Id== maxResult);

if(update!= null)
    update.IsLastMatch= true;
```

Comment: thanks! I could do that! I would only have been extracting much more rows than what I truly need, so that's why I wanted to do the filtering before extracting the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing. Please if you see any improvements let me know!

```
    public async Task<ParticipantTournament> GetParticipantTournamentByDescending(int tournamentId, int participantId)
    {
        var lastMatchId = await _dbRepositories.TournamentParticipantMatchRepository
            .Where(x => x.TournamentId == tournamentId)
            .OrderByDescending(y => y.TournamentMatch.RoundNumber)
            .ThenByDescending(y => y.TournamentMatch.Id)
            .Select(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

         var response = await _dbRepositories.TournamentParticipantMatchRepository
            .Where(x => x.TournamentId == tournamentId)
            .Where(x => (x.Participant1Id == participantId || x.Participant2Id == participantId))
            .Include(x => x.Tournament)
            .Include(x => x.Participant1)
            .Include(x => x.Participant2)
            .Include(x => x.TournamentMatch)
            .ToListAsync();

           var logic = response.Select(z=> new TournamentParticipantMatchLogicDto
            {
                IsLastMatch = z.Id == lastMatchId,
                TournamentParticipantMatch = z
            })
            ;
        return new ParticipantTournament
        {
            ParticipantMatches = logic,
        };


    }
```